# Java HQL org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql, hsqldb

I am using Spring 3 with Hibernate 3. I am using the DAO design pattern and using HQL to query the database. However, when searching for data that does not exist for a field I get the following Exception:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ADDRESS2
```

I am using Liquidbase to manage the database XML schema that creates the tables. Below is the sample code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message() {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String address;

    public Message() {

    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

The following HQL is used from the DAO:

```
 getHibernateTemplate().find("FROM Message m WHERE m.address = address2");
```

The following properties are being set:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb'shutdown=true
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

I cannot find a solution. I can successfully insert a record and also use the same HQL query to find objects with actual values that have been saved, but the problem is with finding values that don't exist.

Comment: Had same problem, but for me solution was just adding the right dialect. (Previously had mysql), cause I had reconnected to that. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FROM Message m WHERE m.address = address2
```

This query looks for messages whoses `address` field is equal to their `address2` field. But messages don't have an `address2` field. If your intention is to find all messages whose `address` field has the value "address2", then the query is

```
FROM Message m WHERE m.address = 'address2'
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 getHibernateTemplate().find("FROM Message m WHERE m.address = 'address2'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Database URL:

You may need to put the full path of database

For example,
jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/10617136/dev/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb/bin/test

Answer (score 0):

I feel wired. After I changed my field name from `profileImage` to `image`, i.e., making it all lowercase, the problem is solved.